# Got an Exception from JPA after adding additional getter and setter

Tags: java, jpa

I've had a jpa entity which worked correctly, but after I added new getter and setter, it comes to return exception below:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: NamedQuery of name: BedOccupation.findByDateofstay not found.
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.getDatabaseQueryInternal(QueryImpl.java:351)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createNamedQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1124)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.createNamedQuery(EntityManagerImpl.java:1144)
    at tcyh.BedOccupationModel.fetchBO(BedOccupationModel.java:42)
    at tcyh.BedOccupationModel.fetchBO(BedOccupationModel.java:48)
    at tcyh.MainWindowController.selectTab(MainWindowController.java:382)
    at tcyh.MainWindowController.initialize(MainWindowController.java:184)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
    ... 14 more
```

I surely have the named query defined in the entity BedOccupation, so I guess this is just because of getter and setter which gets or sets List instead of String.
Here are some codes:

```
BedOccupation fetchBO(Date date) {
    EntityManager em = ConnectTCYHPU.getInstance().getEM();
    TypedQuery tquery = em.createNamedQuery("BedOccupation.findByDateofstay", BedOccupation.class);
    tquery.setParameter("dateofstay", date);
    return (BedOccupation) tquery.setHint(QueryHints.REFRESH, HintValues.TRUE).getSingleResult();
}

....

@Entity
@Table(name = "BEDOCCUPATION")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "BedOccupation.findByDateofstay", query = "SELECT r FROM BedOccupation r WHERE r.dateofstay = :dateofstay"),

....

public class BedOccupation implements Serializable, Cloneable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Id
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "DATEOFSTAY")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date dateofstay;
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "MDORM")
    private String mdorm;

....

//These are getter/setter generated by NetBeans
public String getMDorm() {
    return mdorm;
}
public void setMDorm(String mdorm) {
    this.mdorm = mdorm;
}

//These are getter/setter I added.
public List<String> getMDormList() {
    return CSVToList(mdorm);
}
public void setMDormList(List<String> mdormList) {
    this.mdorm = listToCSV(mdormList);
}

....

private List<String> CSVToList(String str) {
    List list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.addAll(Arrays.asList(str.split(",", -1)));
    return list;
}

private String listToCSV(List list) {
    StringBuilder strb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        strb.append(list.get(i));
        if (i < list.size() - 1) {
            strb.append(",");
        }
    }
    return strb.toString();
}
```

Should I need to put some Annotations or do anything else, to add setter/getter which is not associated to the fields?

Comment: Could it be that the entity is not included in the persistence.xml?  Or it had errors? Do you have other tests which use this entity that work?

Comment: The entity is included in persistence.xml and before I added the getter/setter of list, it worked correctly.

But I'm sorry this might be caused by the other changes....
I'll be back when I would find the actual cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the error on my first post was caused by these methods defined in the entity class BedOccupation:

```
static Comparator<String> compare(){
    return (String a, String b) -> {
        if (a.equals("")) {
            return b.equals("") ? 0 : 1;
        } else if (b.equals("")) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return a.compareTo(b);
        }
    };
}

static Comparator<String> compareOrderDesc(){
    return (String aStr,String bStr) -> {
        if(aStr.equals("")) return 1;
        else if (bStr.equals("")) return -1;
        String[] a = aStr.split("_");
        String[] b = bStr.split("_");
        if (a[0].equals(b[0]) && a.length >= 2 && b.length >= 2){
            return - Integer.decode(a[1])
                    .compareTo(Integer.decode(b[1]));
        }
        return Integer.decode(a[0])
                .compareTo(Integer.decode(b[0]));
    };
}
```

What I want to do in this method is to sort number separated by "_" according to 2nd value of each 1st value.

When I change these codes as below, the error won't occur:

```
static Comparator<String> compare(){
    return new Comparator() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }
    };
}

static Comparator<String> compareOrderDesc(){
    return new Comparator() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }
    };
}
```

I need to search more about it, but would it be a bug?
Anyway, thank you for the help, I'm gonna try to resolve the problem by myself.

Comment: I updated eclipselink.jar to the latest version, then the error disappeared.
It seems it was a bug.